# SEO optimization gone not so well

Tags: seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am relatively new to WordPress, but I want to create a blog and try to optimize it for SEO. 
So I tested my site on `OnPage.org` and it tells me that my site in not indexable due to `robots.txt` settings: "Uhoh - this page will not get into Search Engines, because it is set to "noindex".

I use the Yoast SEO plugin.

Comment: Hi, please head over to `Settings > Reading` and make sure the `Discourage search engines from indexing this site` option is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your Robots.txt file, make it something like this:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow:
```